# Finding rows with matching id's and the using the date fields in each row to find the time difference in days between them

Tags: date, excel-formula, comparison

I have rows of data where up to 3 id's match.  I need to try and find the number of days between each of the rows with matching id's using the date field.  I am looking to find the number of days between each row in date sequence.  So between the first and second row in date sequence, or second and third row but not the first and third row.

So a simplified version of my rows can be seen in the attached image.

[image showing 2 ID's with multiple entries. John Smith (highlight yellow) who has 3 entries, two on the same day and one later and Bill Wright who has just two entries on separate days.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZzTl.png)

The results I would be looking for would ideally be shown in  column 4 of the image.

Is there any way I can do this in a formula or pivot table? (basically avoiding VBA) Any suggestions hugely appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Andrej, thanks for the edits, (I believe) you made to make this readable!

Comment: Your post has gone 'under the radar' as it wasn't tagged with excel-formula. I looked at your issue, but I think your dataset is too small, i.e. it would be nice to have an example with 3 ids; also, you talk about getting the number of days between each row in date sequence (even though your data are not in date sequence, 14/04 coming _before_ 13/04) 'but not the first and third row', yet the first >0 value in your date column _is_ between the 'first and third row'... basically, a larger dataset would reduce the scope for confusion (please also include your version of Excel in your edit).

Comment: @SpectralInstance Thanks for the feedback and suggestions! As you probably guessed this is my first post so I appreciate you help.  I’ll provide a better data set and put it up and add the tag excel-formula.

Answer (score 0):

This [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula)

```
=IFERROR(B2-INDEX($B$1:$B$9,MAX((A2=$A$1:A1)*ROW($A$1:A1))),0)
```

will work as long as your data are sorted by date (which your screenshot indicates they are):
[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed formula producing correct results]

Comment: Thank you so much for coming back to me on this. I have tried it out and once I read the link you provided, as to how array formula need to be entered, it works!   I am still trying to work out how it works :-) but that is a good learning exercise for me.  Thanks again.